# How to get combined code coverage for a Universal App?

Tags: xcode, xctest

If you have a Universal App (iPhone and iPad) which has code which only executes on either of the platforms, does anyone know how to run tests on 2 simulators (1 iPhone and 1 iPad) and combining the code coverage report?  I've looked at Slather, then looked at XC Test Plan, but I can't see how to set the simulator for each of the 2 Test Plan configurations?  I tried setting the destination platform as an argument, but it didn't work. and then there's the combining.

Answer (score 5):

You should run tests with bash command `xcodebuild` and pass multiple destinations at once.

Alternatively, you can use bash command `xcrun xcresulttool merge` to merge multiple xcresult files. This way you'll get the combined coverage report (with the ability to see by platform)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll give it a try. I didn't know it was supported out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
xcrun xcresulttool merge /path/to/first.xcresult /path/to/second.xcresult --output-path final.xcresult
```